# ERD_Help with multiple types of entity

Tags: erd

I am a little confused on the multiple value entity.Please help me to clarify it.
I have a example like this :

> There are many categories of artworks based on their ‘true type’. There are three main types: (i) painting; (ii) sculpture; (iii) statue. Any artworks that cannot be classified in these three main types will be identified as ‘other’.

So, can I group 3 main type "painting","sculpture","statue" by entity "Type" ? if they are in 1 group, how about type "other" ?
If i have to divide these types in many entities ? can some on please tell me the solution.
Much appreciate for your reply

Answer (score 0):

In the Extended ER (EER) model, the terms specialization/generalization are the buzzwords that the describe the relationships between subtypes and supertypes.  There are specific diagramming conventions for diagramming these kinds of relationships in EER diagrams.

Knowing how to diagram them isn't the same thing as knowing how to design tables to fit this kind of situation. You may want to look into [single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) and [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) to see a couple of techniques that may apply to your case.